Hypernetwork too many parameters problem
I want to use a hypernetwork on an entire vision backbone (39m parameters).
The hypernetwork structure looks like:
512 -> 512 -> 512 -> 39m
Unfortunately, the last layer means the hypernetwork has billions of parameters.
What could I do to reduce the parameter count of the hypernetwork?
(The 512-dimensional input vector is a noise vector that acts like a key that describes what details to focus on).

why do you need a hypernetwork for such a large model? what kind of task are you trying to solve?

2 convnet encoders for multimodal embedding and 1 decoder for one of the modalities. The entire network is conditioned by a noise vector for embedding diversity under uncertainty.

just pass the noise as part of the input
